# adding security to spring petclinic

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to learn Spring security, and I want to add security functionality to the spring petclinic sample application (the code for which is [at this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/)).  However, there are problems with the samples on the web.

For example, I would like to use [this example](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-security-mysql-hibernate/), but it uses .java files in an init folder (which you can view [at this link](https://github.com/Fruzenshtein/security-spr/tree/master/src/main/java/com/sprsec/init)) to do tasks which I think the petclinic application does using xml files (which you can view [at this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/tree/master/src/main/resources/spring)).

I want to stick with the xml approach because I have spent many months using xml configuration, but I do not understand the difference between using the xml configuration and java configuration.

**Can someone help me understand what changes I would have to make to [this example](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-security-mysql-hibernate/) in order to get it to work with the xml configuration in the spring petclinic app?**

Alternatively, if you can show a quick and easy way to get working security up and running on the spring petclinic app so that I can start learning by tinkering with working code, that would be OK also.

I started using the spring tutorial for adding security to the petclinic app ([at this link](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-security/tags/release_2_0_0_RC1/src/site/apt/petclinic-tutorial.apt)), but it is not usable because it is many years old and uses an obsolete version of spring.

---

### EDIT:

Based  on JHadesDev's suggestion, I created a new package called `org.springframework.security.samples.petclinic.config` and placed the following two files in it:

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

```
@Order(2)
public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {}
```

Trying to run the app then caused an error indicating that Tomcat would not start because a `SpringSecurityFilterChain` needed to be identified, so I then altered my `web.xml` to include it.  You can read my entire `web.xml` [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/80ayRViVNH8tFuhTmT04?b=pY1CVV1Fi6wfGHdwEYZ1).

But now the changes in `web.xml` are causing an error indicating that Tomcat will not start because the definition of `SpringSecurityFilterChain` is redundant.  I have posted the entire stack trace on a file sharing site that you can read [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/elILf9azml8yZLun2jro?b=jVOllw0FKSZvPLU8A2AO).

How can I get rid of this error so that tomcat will start, and so that login functionality will be enabled for the app?

Answer (score 0):

put this java configuration next to other `@Config` files:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
}
```

This configuration ensures that all urls are secured in the application, and that a default login page is generated. This would be a good starting point, see also this [tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html) that goes through Spring security setup using Java config (instead of XML).

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  I don't understand your answer. Do you mind being more explicit? For starters, are you saying to add your `SecurityConfig` class to this folder in the petclinic app? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/tree/master/src/main/resources/spring

Comment: I reframed this problem into another, clearer, question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670646/where-do-i-define-springsecurityfilterchain-bean