# Can not set spring.example.service.UsuarioService field spring.example.config.security.SecurityConfig.usuario to $Proxy47

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I run my web application, I am facing this error:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private spring.example.service.UsuarioService spring.example.config.security.SecurityConfig.usuario; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set spring.example.service.UsuarioService field spring.example.config.security.SecurityConfig.usuario to $Proxy47
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4959)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1074)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:554)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1649)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1447)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:437)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private spring.example.service.UsuarioService spring.example.config.security.SecurityConfig.usuario; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set spring.example.service.UsuarioService field spring.example.config.security.SecurityConfig.usuario to $Proxy47
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set spring.example.service.UsuarioService field spring.example.config.security.SecurityConfig.usuario to $Proxy47
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:680)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:504)
    ... 59 more
```

which I guess is related to autowired atribute from this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value="spring.example")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuario;

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(usuario)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    private Md5PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/acesso/erro").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/acesso/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("senha")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/acesso/start")
                .failureUrl("/acesso/login")
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .key("lembrete")
                .useSecureCookie(true)
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/acesso/login").permitAll();
    }

}
```

My class UsuarioService.java have this implementation:

```
@Service
public class UsuarioService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UsuarioDao usuario;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String arg0) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario account = usuario.findByField("login", arg0);

        if(account==null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + arg0);
        } else if (account.getAutorizacao().isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + arg0 + " has no authorities");
                    }

        boolean accountIsEnabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new User(account.getLogin(), account.getSenha(), accountIsEnabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, getAuthorities(account.getAutorizacao()));

    }

    public List<String> getRolesAsList(List<Autorizacao> list) {
        List <String> rolesAsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Autorizacao role : list){
            rolesAsList.add(role.getNome());
        }
        return rolesAsList;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(List<Autorizacao> list) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRolesAsList(list));
        return authList;
    }

}
```

What can point me the right direction here? I supose there another way to use this Service class in my SecurityConfig class, but I can find any difference from my code to others available on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are autowiring a concrete class (`UsuarioService`) in SpringConfig instead of an interface (`UserDetailsService`). Take a look at point 2) in [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750241/defining-bean-for-custom-userdetailsservice/22791720#22791720) .

You should autowire `UserDetailsService` like this in your config:

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService usuario;
```

Comment: Ok, I can try this now, but when I need (and I will) a custom UserDetailsService Implementation?

Comment: You have already provided custom implementation with `UsuarioService` class which implements `UserDetailsService` and is a Spring managed bean. Spring will inject (and use) that implementation when wiring UserDetailsService dependency in config.